# Is $f(n)$ asymptotic to $g(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

$\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function and $li(n)$ is the logarithmic integral. $$f(n)=e^{-\frac{1}{\pi\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)}}$$
and $$ g(n)=e^{-\frac{1}{li\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)}}$$

> Is $f(n)\sim g(n)?$ (asymptotic).

$f(n)$ and $g(n)$ seem to grow "closer" to one another not "further" apart, as $n\to 0.$

[image]

Comment: Wait, are you asking as $n\to 0$? If so, why did you include the $\frac{1}{n}$ in the functions. why not just $n$ and consider what happens as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: If $n>0.5$ then $\frac{1}{n} < 2 $ and so $\pi(\frac{1}{n}) =0$ and the function $f(n)$ has no meaning so the valid interval for $n$ is $ 0<n\leq 0.5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{1}{n}$ and so when $n \to 0^{+}$  then $x \to \infty$ and we need to prove that $ f(x) \sim g(x) $

Since e(exp) is continues function then $ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) =\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\pi(x)}} = e^{\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} -\frac{1}{\pi(x)}} = e^0 =1$ ($\pi(x)$ is not bounded from above, there are infinitely many primes).

Also $ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-\frac{1}{li(x)}} = e^{\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} -\frac{1}{li(x)}} = e^0=1$ ($ li(x) > \frac{x}{\ln x}$)

And so $f(x) \sim 1 \sim g(x) \implies f(x) \sim g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ or $ n \to 0^+$